# jQuery - get the selected options of a listitem collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have fields that a user would enter and i would pass it into jQuery and pass to a web service.

I can get textboxes values by:

var name =  $("#MainContent_txtName").val()

The problem I'm having is a multi-select that comprises of a list item collection. 
If I was to do this server side, I would do something like:

```
foreach (ListItem li in listTitles)
{
   if (li.Selected)
   {
     selectedValue += li.Value + ",";
   }
}
```

And this would give me the string of selected values from the select list.
I'm having trouble getting it out from jQuery. 
If I do

```
var titles = $("#MainContent_selectListTitles").val()
```

That is obviously incorrect because it won't bring back the selected list items.
I saw a post that suggested that I could retrieve it if I say option selected. 
So I tried this:

```
var titles= $('#MainContent_selectListTitles option:selected');
```

The next thing I did was pop an alert to see what the titles were.  It just said [object, object].

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to get the selected items from the list item collection concatenated into a string?
2. Or is it better that I get all the form values from a postback even on my code behind and then call the jquery function?  If this is an option, i've attempted to do this but have failed.  It tells me that it can't find the method. So i'm definitely not calling the jquery function correctly on postback of the button event.

THanks.

Comment: Ok, so I got it working now. Forgive me as this is my first time using jQuery.

I use this to get each selected option:
  $("#MainContent_msClaimantType :checked").each(function () {
          alert($(this).text());

Now this pops up an alert for each selected option.
So the question now becomes how do I concatenate the selected options into a variable?  thanks.

Comment: i would go with option #1 and i did similar to #1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your item id is correct on client side that is "MainContent_selectListTitles". You can check it by "View Source".

If the ID is correct, follow this.

```
    $('#MainContent_selectListTitles').change(function () {
         var str = "";
         $('#MainContent_selectListTitles option:selected').each(function () {
              str += $(this).text() + " ";
              //pass str value to your web service here.
         });
    }).trigger('change');
```

Every time there is changes, it will call this function which means it will make your web service busy. You can move the above code to button click event if you want.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail and Jonas.
I actually had it working but tried your methods as well to prove that yours work as well.  Mine was actually very similar to what Jonas had.  I was a fool. I had var str = "" inside of the each(function).  No wonder why there was nothing in it when I tried to pass it via web service. 

THanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised that you've got [object, object] in your alert - that's because you've had and array of selected items (actually, two items were selected) and alert displayed your array as [object, object] which is fine.

Having the following html markup:

```
    <div>
        <select multiple="multiple" id="mySelect">
            <option value="test1" selected="selected">Test 1</option>
            <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="test3" selected="selected">Test 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

And the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ready = function () {
        var selectedItems = $("#mySelect option:selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            alert("The value is: "+selectedItems[i].value + "; the text is: "+selectedItems[i].text);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Will probably solve your problem.

Actually, binding the data manually is a huge pain and I do recommend you to look on the modern MVVM libraries like knockout.js.
For instance:
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/controlTypes.html